# S3 Bucket Policy - Allow EC2 Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My CI pipeline deposits intermediate artifacts in an S3 bucket that I don't want to be accessible to the public, but that does need to be accessible to myself and certain IP addresses.

Currently I have the following bucket permission policy in place:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "CIBucketPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IpAllowList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ci-bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ci-bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "ip-address1",
                        "ip-address2",
                        "ip-address3"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

One of the artifacts that my CI deposits here is a raw disk image, which is used in later stages to build an Amazon Machine Image using `aws ec2 import-snapshot`. The problem here is that the `aws ec2 import-snapshot` stage keeps failing with the error message:

```
ClientError: Disk validation failed [We do not have access to the given resource. Reason 403 Forbidden]
```

I'm fairly confident that something about my bucket permission policy is blocking `ec2` from being able to access the bucket even though they're in the same availability zone, but I haven't figured out how to overcome this without simply removing the IP address condition.

Do I need to add something special to this policy for EC2 to have access? Perhaps I'm missing an S3 Action that EC2 needs to be able to perform in order to access the image file? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `aws ec2 import-snapshot` is not accessing S3 directly from the EC2 instance. It is telling the AWS EC2 snapshot service to go import a snapshot from S3. You need to allow access to the Principal that the EC2 Snapshot service is using, instead of an IP address. Unfortunately I'm not finding what that principal is going to be, it may be your AWS root account, or it may be an AWS service role. The easiest way to debug this further would be to look at the failed API call in CloudTrail to see what principal is being used.

Comment: Okay, thank you I will check CloudTrail and see what if I can answer the open question here of what the principal is. Thank you!